# The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring 4.1 and my  Rest Controller signature looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/device")
public class ApiRestController {

   public ResponseEntity<Response> singleResponse() {
        System.out.println("SDR GET");
        SingleDataResponse res = new SingleDataResponse();
        res.setCmd("8028");
        res.setData("xyz");
        res.setRfu("rfu");
        res.setSid("99");
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/single-res-post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> singleResponsePost(
            @RequestBody SingleDataRequest req, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("SDR Post");
        SingleDataResponse res = new SingleDataResponse();
        res.setCmd(req.getCmd());
        res.setRfu(req.getRfu());
        res.setSid(req.getSid());
        res.setData("0");
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I have added the below Bean in my WebMvcConfig

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    adapter.setCacheSecondsForSessionAttributeHandlers(0);
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverter = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    httpMessageConverter.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);

    String[] supportedHttpMethods = { "POST", "GET", "HEAD" };

    adapter.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverter);
    adapter.setSupportedMethods(supportedHttpMethods);

    return adapter;
}
```

I am using HttpClient for Get and Post to access the above rest api

I able to acess the Get Request but while sending the Post request I am getting the response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.12 - Error report</title></head>
<body>
   <h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported</h1>
   <p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'POST' not supported</u></p>
   <p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u></p>
</body></html>
```

Kindly suggest

The code used to send the post request

```
public static void verifyIreoWSPost() throws Exception {
        String wms = "http://localhost:8080/test-rest/api/device/single-res-post";
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String json = "{\"sid\":\"99\",\"rfu\":\"rfu\",\"cmd\":\"8028\",\"data\":\"xyz\"}";
        headers.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        headers.put("username", "admin");
        headers.put("password", "admin");
        String response = HttpUtils.sendPost(wms, headers, json);
        System.out.println("post response: " + response);
    }
```

Comment: Which URL did you send the request to?

Comment: public static void verifyIreoWSPost() throws Exception {
  String wms = "http://localhost:8080/test-rest/api/device/single-res-post";
  Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
  String json = "{\"sid\":\"99\",\"rfu\":\"rfu\",\"cmd\":\"8028\",\"data\":\"xyz\"}";
  headers.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
  headers.put("username", "admin");
  headers.put("password", "admin");
  String response = HttpUtils.sendPost(wms, headers, json);
  System.out.println("post response: " + response);
 }

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit your question and put it there.